# Most efficient way to finding substrings in php

Tags: php

I've been made the following question during a hiring process skills test:

> Assuming a large random string, eg:
>
> `$x = str_shuffle(str_repeat(implode('', range('a', 'z')), 1000000));`
>
> What's the most efficient way to find substrings on it?

And I'd like to know the answer just to learn about it.

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: I dislike those interview questions and what comes first to my mind is "throw some money on fast hardware and be done with it". Such questions, if you must have them, should imho be phrased as "Discuss some approaches to the problem and their consequences". "Substrings" means several at a time? Exactly what is meant by efficient? (quick to implement, robust, maintainable, parallelizable, ...?) And many more open questions to make this even slightly meaningful....

Comment: Question is too ambiguous. I agree with @VolkerK entirely. It was never specified what a *substring* would be (1 character, multiple characters). This question looks like a poor attempt at "hidden" real question - the problem is known as [Longest Common Substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). The link includes explanations as well. Unless there's a substantial explanation of the problem, the fastest way is to `strpos` since you can't do anything else really.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I agree with you that the question is too ambiguous. My answered was that the most efficient way of finding substrings in php is using `strpos`, but I wanted to be sure about that.

Comment: "finding substrings in php" - Oh, IN php, so the C extension implementing a [of course parallel] version of the Boyer-Moore algorithm is out of the question? Darn, I thought the answer was _so_ obvious ;-) Of course the problem can be discussed; it's not a stupid question per se, far from it. My problem with it is that I've seen such _interview_ questions thrown in witlessly without context too often. The "excuse" is often "we don't care about the exact answer; we want to see how the applicant approaches the problem"; but without good evidence for that I don't buy that anymore ...

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
<?php
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
   echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that's one option but I'd also like to know other user's opinions just to know if that's the most efficient way

Answer (score 2):

The options you have are:

`strpos()`, `preg_match()` for regular expression matches and `stripos()` for **case-insensitive** searches.

The regex matching will be always slower than plain strings searches. But here is a comparison considering case sentive or insensitive strings in plain installations of PHP:

*This data was obtained from `10000` searches in a `1k` string.*

```
php5-cgi        strpos()        27.7 ms
mod_php5        strpos()        30.6 ms
mod_php5 + ZP   strpos()        37.2 ms
php5-cgi        stripos()       163.6 ms
mod_php5        stripos()       172.8 ms
mod_php5 + ZP   stripos()       177.3 ms
php5-cgi        preg_match()    72.2 ms
```

[Source](https://lzone.de/articles/php-string-search.htm)